# Algorithm2e writing simple pseudocode with multiple functions

Tags: algorithm2e

I am new at `algorithm2e` and I'm really struggling with the most simple things.

I would like to write an algorithm (pseudocode) with a few functions that call each other. For now, I have this minimal (not)working example:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \caption{Some algorithm}
    \label{alg:some-algorithm}
    \DontPrintSemicolon

    \SetKwFunction{FMain}{Main}
    \SetKwFunction{FTest}{Test}

    \FMain{$f$, $a$, $b$, $\varepsilon$}{
        a\;
        b\;
        \KwRet\;
    }

    \FTest{$f$, $a$, $b$}{
        a\;
        b\;
        \KwRet\;
    }
\end{algorithm}
```

The output is the following:
[image: output]

As you can see, the first line of code `a` is on the same line as the function definition. Also, nothing is indented and the whole thing looks rather ugly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding an empty line between the `\FMain{$f$, $a$, $b$, $\varepsilon$}{` and the `a\;` ?

Comment: Are you interested in something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ADTev.png)? That is, where you have an "algorithm" that is defined as a set of functions and/or procedures?

Comment: @Werner: yes, Your example looks OK. I would like to have one `Main` procedure/function along with two other procedures/functions.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As the documentation (try `texdoc algorithm2e` on the command line or search for `algorithm2e.pdf`) says:

> `\SetKwFunction{KwFn}{Fn}` defines a macro `\KwFn{arg}` which prints `Fn` in Function typography and its argument `arg` in argument typography, surrounded by a pair of parentheses.

In particular, `\FMain` and `FTest` both have only a single argument.  They are used to correctly typeset a function name, not to define a new function.  To typeset a *function definition*, use `\SetKwProg{Prog}{Title}{is}{end}`.

EDIT: The following example is in the documentation:

```
\SetAlgoLined
\SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{ is}{end}
\Fn{afunc(i: int) : int}{return 0\;}

\SetKwProg{Def}{def}{:}{}
\Def{afunc(i: int)}{return 0\;}
```

leads to:

```
1 Function afunc(i: int) : int is
2 | return 0;
3 end
4 def afunc(i: int):
5 | return 0;
```

So the idea is that `\SetKwProg` defines a template for functions (e.g. `\Fn` or `\Def`).  `\Fn` and `\Def` themselves now have *two* arguments, one for the header and one for the body of the function.

To adapt your example:

```
\begin{algorithm}
  \DontPrintSemicolon
  \SetKwFunction{FMain}{Main}
  \SetKwProg{Fn}{Function}{:}{}
  \Fn{\FMain{$f$, $a$, $b$, $\varepsilon$}}{
        a\;
        b\;
        \KwRet\;
  }
  \;
  \SetKwProg{Pn}{Function}{:}{\KwRet}
  \Pn{\FMain{$f$, $a$, $b$, $\varepsilon$}}{
        a\;
        b\;
  }
\end{algorithm}
```

gives

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it was really helpful. I didn't know that I also need to use the `\SetKwProg` in order to define the function.